# Images inside table are drawn on top of cell borders

Tags: tables, graphics

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
\hline
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{image1.png} & \includegraphics[scale=.5]{image2.png} \\
\hline
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{image3.png} & \includegraphics[scale=.5]{image4.png} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The problem is that the images seem to be on top of cell borders and hide them. Can I add some padding to prevent them from being over the borders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the image in a `\fbox{}`and set the 
space around it. But use `@{}` in tabular columns. See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Command just to avoid too much typing in tabular 
\newcommand{\imgtest}{
  \framebox{
   \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{img.jpg}}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}
\hline
\imgtest & \imgtest \\
\hline
\imgtest & \imgtest \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}
\imgtest & \imgtest \\
\imgtest & \imgtest \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Other solution could be make a minipage in each cell instead of a framed box (modify the lengths as needed):

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\vspace{1mm}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{image1.png}
\vspace{1mm}
\end{minipage}
```

But if you do not want to see the vertical lines in the table (ie, `{cc}` instead of `{|c|c|}`) a `\\` after `\hline` might be enough.

Finally: May be do you are searching for a float with subfigures instead of a table with figures? In this case, see the package `subcaption`.